# Creating dynamic table using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to create a dynamic table using PHP but what I get is in each column of my table the array goes to the end and the next column is staring from the 0 to the end.

I tried to put if conditions and do some tricks to fix it but I couldn't.
this is the result I get for below code :

[image]

```
<?php
    $query_formsearch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `forms` ");
    $query_usr_prvlg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION["usr_id"]}' ");
    $usr_access=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_usr_prvlg);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query_formsearch);
    $i=0;
?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
<?php   while($forms_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_formsearch))
        {
            $f_num="form_".$forms_row['num']; 

?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if(($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-1") || ($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-0")) ?>
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="hidden"  id="form-name" name ="form-name" value="<?php echo $forms_row['num']; ?>" />
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="submit"  id="sbmt-btn" name ="sbmt-btn" value="<?php echo $forms_row['name']; ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php if(($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-1") || ($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-0")) ?>
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="hidden"  id="form-name" name ="form-name" value="<?php echo $forms_row['num']; ?>" />
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="submit"  id="sbmt-btn" name ="sbmt-btn" value="<?php echo $forms_row['name']; ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php if(($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-1") || ($usr_access[$f_num]=="1-0")) ?>
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="hidden"  id="form-name" name ="form-name" value="<?php echo $forms_row['num']; ?>" />
                    <input  class='styled-input_m' type="submit"  id="sbmt-btn" name ="sbmt-btn" value="<?php echo $forms_row['name']; ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php           

    }
?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: no body knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Actually nobody understands what you are trying to explain!